# How do I use AJAX to display the data from a json file in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I'm working with jQuery to AJAX a .json file and display it in a bootstrap table. I've been able to create a template for the table in my html file. The .json file I have is local, but I'm not sure how to display it in the table. I'm starting out, and reading tutorials on how to code this. Here is what I have so far:

Here is what is in my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/bootstrap-table/src/bootstrap-table.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class = "container">

        <table table id = "table" data-url="students.json">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field = "fname">First Name</th>
                    <th data-field = "lname">Last Name</th>
                    <th data-field = "startDate">Start Date</th>
                    <th data-field = "street">Street</th>
                    <th data-field = "city">City</th>
                    <th data-field = "state">State</th>
                    <th data-field = "zip">Zip Code</th>
                    <th data-field = "phone">Phone</th>
                    <th data-field = "year">Year</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a snippet of the type of data that is in the json file.

```
{
    "fname": "Lois",
    "lname": "Hanson",
    "startDate": "3/12/93",
    "street": "923 North 1400 East",
    "city": "Williamsburg",
    "state": "ID",
    "zip": 93673,
    "phone": "673-3114",
    "year": 4
},
```

Would I be able to write all the code in an html file?

Comment: Loop through the AJAX response and appendChild tr for each record.  That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an `ajax` call to get the local json file. Parse it and bind it to `html` element. i.e `table` in your case.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'students.json',
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'json',
  error: function(data){
  },
  success: function(data){
     $('#table').append(data);             
  }
});
```

wrap the above code into a `javascript` function and make sure it executes on the load of your `html`.

Answer (score 0):

First create a JavaScript file into your directory and append to the Html file, then wrap the below code in this file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'students.json',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(data){
        },
        success: function(data){
            var tr = $('<tr>');
            tr.append('<td>' + data.fname + '<td>');
            tr.append('<td>' + data.lname + '<td>');
            tr.append('<td>' + data.startDate + '<td>');
            tr.append('<td>' + data.city + '<td>');
            tr.append('<td>' + data.state + '<td>');
            tr.append('<td>' + data.zip + '<td>');
            tr.append('<td>' + data.phone + '<td>');
            tr.append('<td>' + data.year + '<td>');

            $('#table').append(tr);           
        }
    });
});
```